# How to get the currently selected Menu or MenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

How can I retrieve the currently selected menu or menu item when clicked on it and the subsequent path will be printed on console. In this code I have done the menus and sub menus up to 4 levels. And want to print the path of selected menus and submenus when clicked on. I am using swing concept for this program. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.MenuElement;
import javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Menu {

  public static void main(final String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MenuSample Example");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

JMenu worldMenu = new JMenu("world");
menuBar.add(worldMenu);


JMenu indMenu = new JMenu("India");
worldMenu.add(indMenu);
/* creates menu */
JMenu odMenu = new JMenu("Odisha");
indMenu.add(odMenu);

JMenu delhiMenu = new JMenu("Delhi");
indMenu.add(delhiMenu);

JMenu upMenu = new JMenu("Uttar Pradesh");
indMenu.add(upMenu);

JMenu mpMenu = new JMenu("Madhya Pradesh");
    indMenu.add(mpMenu);

    JMenu ausMenu = new JMenu("Australia");
worldMenu.add(ausMenu);

JMenu AmericaMenu = new JMenu("America");
worldMenu.add(AmericaMenu);

/* creates submenu */
JMenu bbMenu = new JMenu("Bhubaneswar");
odMenu.add(bbMenu);

JMenu bmMenu = new JMenu("Berhampur");
odMenu.add(bmMenu);
/*creates sub sub menu */
JMenuItem rjMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Raj Mahal");
bbMenu.add(rjMenuItem);

JMenuItem abMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Acharya Bihar");
bbMenu.add(abMenuItem);

JMenuItem bnMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Bani Bihar");
bbMenu.add(bnMenuItem);
/* retrieving path */

MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager().addChangeListener(
        new ChangeListener() {
          public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {

            MenuElement[] path = MenuSelectionManager.defaultManager()
                .getSelectedPath();

            //
            int s=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                Component c = path[i].getComponent();
                if (c instanceof JMenuItem) {
                JMenuItem mi = (JMenuItem) c;
                String label = mi.getText();
                System.out.println("LEVEL----" + s);
                System.out.println("you hv selected:"+label);
                s++;


              }
            }

          }
        });

    //

    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.setSize(350, 250);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: please post what you tried?

Comment: posted the code  @TamilSelvan

Comment: And what's not working in your code?

Comment: when i hover over menus it shows the visited menus,i want to modify it as  when clicked the particular menus and sub menus, selected path will be printed @MadProgrammer

Comment: @javajon please help to solve this issue.

Comment: @javajon sir if i wish to print all the menus starting from "World" to "bhubaneswar" then what changes i have to made,please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get the currently selected

1. **Menu** - A parent JMenu cannot be selected. Why would you want to know
   if the mouse is over it?
2. **MenuItem** - Embrace the Action interface

It is an all too common oversight to not use the [Action interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).  When developing with Swing make Action your friend, it will treat you well.  You went down the wrong path with MenuSelectionManager.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MenuExample {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel choiceIndicator;

    MenuExample create() {
        frame = createFrame();
        choiceIndicator = new JLabel();
        frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
        frame.getContentPane().add(createContent());

        return this;
    }

    private Component createContent() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(new JLabel("Last menu item choice:"));
        panel.add(choiceIndicator);

        return panel;
    }

    private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(createWorld());
        return menuBar;
    }

    private JMenu createWorld() {
        JMenu worldMenu = new JMenu("World");

        worldMenu.add(createIndia());
        worldMenu.add(new JMenu("Australia"));
        worldMenu.add(new JMenu("America"));

        return worldMenu;
    }

    private JMenu createIndia() {
        JMenu india = new JMenu("India");

        india.add(createOdisha());
        india.add(new JMenu("Delhi"));
        india.add(new JMenu("Uttar Pradesh"));
        india.add(new JMenu("Madhya Pradesh"));

        return india;
    }

    private JMenuItem createOdisha() {
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Odisha");

        menu.add(createBhubaneswar());
        menu.add(new JMenu("Berhampur"));

        return menu;
    }

    private JMenuItem createBhubaneswar() {
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Bhubaneswar");
        menu.add(choiceItem("Raj Mahal"));
        menu.add(choiceItem("Acharya Bihar"));
        menu.add(choiceItem("Bani Bihar"));

        return menu;
    }

    private JMenuItem choiceItem(String text) {
        return new JMenuItem(new Choice(text, choiceIndicator));
    }

    private JFrame createFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        return frame;
    }

    void show() {
        frame.setSize(350, 250);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MenuExample().create().show();
            }
        });
    }

    class Choice extends AbstractAction {
        private final JLabel choiceIndicator;

        public Choice(String text, JLabel choiceIndicator) {
            this(text, null, null, null, choiceIndicator);
        }

        public Choice(String text, ImageIcon icon, String desc, Integer mnemonic, JLabel choiceIndicator) {
            super(text, icon);
            putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);

            this.choiceIndicator = choiceIndicator;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            choiceIndicator.setText(e.getActionCommand());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir,i will keep in mind all these concepts as mentioned by you .